# Blocking Google Analytics

Tags: google-chrome, google-analytics

How can I block or remove the Google Analytics code so that it does not load when I visit a web page?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @muntoo i am using google chrome

Comment: Grease Monkey may be worth an Investigation

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be invisible to google analytics of some site - the best way to do it is to overwrite Google Analytics URL in windows hosts file:

Open this file in notepad:

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

you will see strings like that:

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
```

add these strings to the end of file:

```
   209.85.225.113  localhost
   209.85.225.138  localhost    
   209.85.225.139  localhost 
   209.85.225.100  localhost 
   209.85.225.101  localhost
   209.85.225.102  localhost
```

that will make all google analytics calls local, i.e. not to actual GA server

Comment: That’s not right at all; those lines just redirect any local connections to Google’s Analytics servers: **the opposite of what was intended**.

Comment: And also this method doesn't work if a new ip is added by google.

Answer (score 3):

You have a few options for extensions you can use. Here they are, in order of most likely to work, and least likely:

- [Ghostery](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mlomiejdfkolichcflejclcbmpeaniij) Extension. It'll block all well-known web-bugs - that means Analytics.
- [AdBlock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom) / [Adblock Plus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb) / [uBlock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm?hl=en) Extension. Add the following code to your manual filters:

  ```
  http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js
  ```
- [ScriptSafe](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/scriptsafe/oiigbmnaadbkfbmpbfijlflahbdbdgdf?hl=en) Extension. Blocks scripts.

---

Answer (score 3):

I just noticed that Chrome (at least v.12) does not request http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js but rather knows the direct IP. blocking www.google-analytics.com in hosts file works for Firefox, other browsers,  direct wget, but Chrome still opens the ga.gs file (I cleared it's cache). Probably there are too many advices on the Internet how to use hosts file, so they "hacked" this method of avoiding their grip, at least in their own browser

Answer (score 2):

You can use a browser plugin. It's not that hard as google's analytics JS is always the same URL.

OR

you could set google-analytics.com to 127.0.0.1 in your host file. Effectively blocking all google analytics js. If you prevent it from keep pinging the server and trying to get the document, you  could point google-analytics.com to a known server that will serve an empty js file.

Note: I believe the google analytics url is google-analytics.com/ga.js Though I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

just put this http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js into AdBlock (for chrome or firefox) and it should work.